# jQuery Datepicker - Enable submit button only if start-end date are not empty

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
$('#datepicker_start').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
              $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","10-03-2015", selected)
            }
    });


$('#datepicker_end').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
              $("#datepicker_start").datepicker("option","09-04-2015", selected)
            }
    });


<button class="btn" id="btn_submit" type="button" disabled="disabled">Submit</button> 


        //enable 'Submit' button only if start-end dates both are not empty
        if( $('#datepicker_start').val().length !=0 && $('#datepicker_end').val().length !=0 ){
            $('#btn_submit').attr('disabled', false);            
        }else{
            $('#btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);
        }
```

The above does not checks the start-end dates input when date is selected from calendar but on document load. How to check input value is empty or not when date is selected from datepicker

Comment: What is the problem in above code? Error or not working?

Comment: Your "*enable submit button only if...*" should be handled by an event. I mean, how do you know when datepickers have a value?

Comment: @kmsdev, that could be handled using onSelect event for datepicker

Comment: Yes, that's it. Other workaround would be to manage your submit button, something like `$('#btn_submit').on('click', function(){ // if datepickers have values return true, else return false  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You can create a function to enable or disable submit button and call it after selecting a date value.

```
$(function(){

   var enableDisableSubmitBtn = function(){
     var startVal = $('#datepicker_start').val().trim();
     var endVal = $('#datepicker_end').val().trim();
     var disableBtn =  startVal.length == 0 ||  endVal.length == 0;
     $('#btn_submit').attr('disabled',disableBtn);
   }

   $('#datepicker_start').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
              $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","10-03-2015", selected);
              enableDisableSubmitBtn();
            }
    });


    $('#datepicker_end').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
              $("#datepicker_start").datepicker("option","09-04-2015", selected);
             enableDisableSubmitBtn();
            }
    });
});


<button class="btn" id="btn_submit" type="button" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pd26m6xs/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can make a check function and call it when you pick a date
some thing like that :

```
function check(){
        if( $('#datepicker_start').val().length !=0 && $('#datepicker_end').val().length !=0 ){
            $('#btn_submit').attr('disabled', false);            
        }else{
            $('#btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);
        }
}
$('#datepicker_start').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
              $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","10-03-2015", selected)
check();
            }
    });


$('#datepicker_end').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
              $("#datepicker_start").datepicker("option","09-04-2015", selected)
            }
    });


<button class="btn" id="btn_submit" type="button" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i suggest you to work within the `onSelect` datepicker's event:

```
$('#datepicker_start').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
     onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","10-03-2015", selected);
        enablebtn($("#btn_submit"), $('#datepicker_start'), $('#datepicker_end')); // use it here and pass the elements
     }
});

$('#datepicker_end').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'd-M-y' ,
     onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#datepicker_start").datepicker("option","09-04-2015", selected);
        enablebtn($("#btn_submit"), $('#datepicker_start'), $('#datepicker_end')); // use it here and pass the elements
     }
});

function enablebtn(btn, startDate, endDate){
    var bool = startDate.val().length && endDate.val().length; // returns true/false;
    btn.prop('disabled', bool); // now it enables when true and disables if false.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
if(isNaN(fromDate) || isNaN(toDate))
{
alert("Please select To/From Date");
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense and has no relation with real issue. Also you will get always a `NaN` from the datepickers values.